# unix "clear" TERM environment variable not set

Tags: c, shell, unix, environment-variables

I am making my own shell and have set up the fork/exec stuff to execute programs. for commands without a '/' I search the PATH environment for directories with the executable in it. However when I try to use clear in my shell, tells me TERM environment variable not set. I am wondering if it has something to do with this:

```
execve(args[0], args, environ);
```

where environ =

```
char* environ[] = {NULL};
```

Is there something I need to put in there? Would prefer not using execvp. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yes, it has a lot to do with that.  You need the environment to include TERM and other values — HOME, PATH spring to mind immediately.  Check POSIX for the minimum set.

Answer (score 1):

The shell is supposed to provide its own environment variables to child processes. In fact, pretty much all processes which spawn children are supposed to do that. Normally you'd use `execv` for that (note the lack of `e`), which doesn't take the environment as a parameter.

A shell is a special case too, since it's one of the processes which may legitimately modify the environment before passing it to its children. This means you probably will end up needing `execve`, but you cannot simply pass a fixed array there. You will need to manage the environment you want to pass to your children, loading your own environment at shell start-up, modifying it during each environment modification command, and passing that as `environ`.

Comment: sorry i am not too familiar with environment. what do you mean by loading your own environment? would that be using saving a variable via getenv and then when I exec a process, i setenv the with the variable

Comment: @ricefieldboy If you consistently modify your own environment (rather than creating a local copy), then you don't need to do much: then it suffices to call `getenv` when the user requests a variable (`echo $HOME`) and to call `(un)setenv` when the user requests modification of a variable (`export var=foo`). Then `execv` will be enough. But this approach doesn't work once you add shell-local variables (`var=foo`). When you add those, you'll need to duplicate `getenv`, `setenv`, `unsetenv` in your program and adjust them to search both environment variables and shell-local variables.